# Adding multiple lines from other dataset to a stacked barchart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I am trying to find a solution on how to add multiple lines on my existing ggplot barchart. I know how to add lines on a barplot in case all data are coming from one dataframe and on how to add lines from other dataset to a simple barchart but I am struggling with adding lines from dataset A to a stacked barchart from a dataset B.

My stacked barchart is created like this:

```
report_Official <- structure(list(Competency.Official.Rating = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("demonstrates the value", "development area", "role model"
), class = "factor"), Competency.Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Co-creating the future", 
"Feedback", "Impact", "One company", "One voice", "Simplification"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(305L, 114L, 70L, 352L, 72L, 80L, 
333L, 88L, 80L, 293L, 38L, 167L, 313L, 20L, 171L, 358L, 59L, 
85L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

ggplot(report_Official, aes(x = Competency.Name, y = Freq, 
                            fill = factor(Competency.Official.Rating, levels = c("role model", "demonstrates the value", "development area")),
                            label = Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +  # position = fill will give the %; stack will give #of people
  geom_text(size = 5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))   + 
#   facet_wrap(  ~ Subject.Direction) +
  labs(x = "Competence Name", 
       y = "Number of Employees") + # or Percentage of Employees [%] or Number of Employees
  theme_bw()  +
  ggtitle("Behavior Official Rating") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5),
                                    face = "bold", vjust = 1.5),
          axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
          #legend.box.background = element_rect(color="red", size=2),
          #legend.box.margin = margin(116, 6, 6, 6),
          legend.key = element_rect(colour = "gray"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8),
          axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5)) +
  # scale_fill_manual(name="Manager Rating", values = wes_palette("Zissou1", n = 5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu")+ #Oranges for Values
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Competency Official Rating")) +
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), text = element_text(size=15), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",
                                     size = 15, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
          axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold",
                                     size = 15, angle = 90))
```

The lines I am trying to add are coming from these three datasets:

```
rm <- structure(list(Competency.Self.Rating = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("demonstrates the value", "development area", 
"role model"), class = "factor"), Competency.Name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Co-creating the future", 
"Feedback", "Impact", "One company", "One voice", "Simplification"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(75L, 94L, 113L, 180L, 189L, 116L
)), row.names = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 18L), class = "data.frame")

dv <- structure(list(Competency.Self.Rating = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("demonstrates the value", "development area", 
"role model"), class = "factor"), Competency.Name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Co-creating the future", 
"Feedback", "Impact", "One company", "One voice", "Simplification"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(309L, 337L, 334L, 286L, 294L, 
338L)), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 16L), class = "data.frame")

da <- structure(list(Competency.Self.Rating = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("demonstrates the value", "development area", 
"role model"), class = "factor"), Competency.Name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Co-creating the future", 
"Feedback", "Impact", "One company", "One voice", "Simplification"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(105L, 73L, 54L, 32L, 21L, 48L)), row.names = c(2L, 
5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried adding to my ggplot the line `geom_point(data = rm, mapping = aes(x = Competency.Name, y = Freq))`,  `geom_point(data = dv, mapping = aes(x = Competency.Name, y = Freq))`, and `geom_point(data = da, mapping = aes(x = Competency.Name, y = Freq))` to add the lines to my stacked barplot but it gives me an error

```
Error in factor(Competency.Official.Rating, levels = c("role model", "demonstrates the value",  : 
  object 'Competency.Official.Rating' not found
```

Anyone knows how I could plot lines from my datasets rm, da, and dv to my stacked barchart? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of putting `fill` in your *global* aesthetic (i.e., the `aes()` inside `ggplot()`), try moving it to be in `aes()` in your `geom_bar()` layer. That way your new `geom_point()` layers won't look for that variable and fail to find it. The global aesthetics pass down to all geoms, so if you want one to just affect one geom it can be easiest to use it only in that layer. If you end up then needing a grouping layer for your text stacking try using the `group` aesthetic.

Comment: In addition, you can make life easier by putting `dv`, `da`, and `rm` in one data frame and passing them all to ggplot at once: `all_point_data <- bind_rows(da,dv,rm); <your_plot_object> + geom_point(data = all_point_data, aes(x=Competency.Name, y=Freq))`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options to fix this. As the comments stated, moving the fill out of the global aesthetic will prevent that error. This is probably the best way to do it, and the easiest. If you don't want to do that, you can either set the fill attribute to `NULL` for all other geoms, or set the `inherit.aes` argument to `FALSE` for them. If `inherit.aes` is set to `FALSE`, then you will need to provide the data, x, and y for each. In the below code I moved the fill to the `aes()` in `geom_bar()`. The points for those data sets are added with `geom_point()` and the lines with `geom_line()`.

```
ggplot(report_Official, aes(x = Competency.Name, 
                            y = Freq, 
                            label = Freq)) +
  geom_bar(data = report_Official,
           aes(fill = factor(Competency.Official.Rating,
                             
                             levels = c("role model", "demonstrates the value", "development area"))),
           stat = "identity") +  # position = fill will give the %; stack will give #of people
  geom_text(size = 5,
            aes(group = factor(Competency.Official.Rating,
                               
                               levels = c("role model", "demonstrates the value", "development area"))), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))   + 
  geom_point(data = rm,
             color = "black") +
  geom_line(data = rm, 
            aes(group = 1)) +
  geom_point(data = dv,
             color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = dv,
            aes(group = 1),
            color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = da,
             color = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = da,
            aes(group = 1),
            color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Competence Name", 
       y = "Number of Employees") + 
  theme_bw()  +
  ggtitle("Behavior Official Rating") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5),
                                  face = "bold", vjust = 1.5),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
        
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "gray"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu")+ #Oranges for Values
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Competency Official Rating")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), text = element_text(size=15), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",
                                   size = 15, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold",
                                   size = 15, angle = 90))
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: To add a legend for each of the data sets that is plotted in the lines, you will need to merge them as a single data set with a column that denotes where they came from.

```
dv$set <- "dv"
da$set <- "da"
rm$set <- "rm"
line_df <- rbind(dv, da, rm)
```

Then you can combine the `geom_line()` into a single call.

```
geom_line(data = line_df,
          aes(color = set,
              group = set)) +
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! it worked. and how should I add the legend for the lines? I have tried ```scale_fill_manual```,  ```scale_color_manual``` but it does not do the trick. Looks like it is overruled by the legend of the bars.

Comment: @MariKo See edit.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it worked. however, I see that the numbers are shifted in the barcolumns. For example, for the first bar 114 should be at the bottom with the dark blue color... It looks like that adding ```aes``` to the ```geom_bar``` creates that behavior... How can I fix it?

Comment: @MariKo Good catch, I edited the answer. You can add a grouping to the `geom_text()` `aes()` call to fix this. You can see this in the first code block.

Comment: thank you! Now it is a perfect barplot =)